# Names DYnamic Range excel with Offset formula lost reference

Tags: excel

I have an offset in a defined name following ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50356642/set-excel-chart-data-series-range-dynamically-by-a-cells-value/50357649?noredirect=1#comment87749436_50357649)), and everything works fine untill I delete and shift up some of the rows. My code is the following:

```
=OFFSET('Acq HORIBA'!$T$3,Rifasamento!$C$40,0,5000-Rifasamento!$C$40+1,1)
```

When I delete the 3rd row the $T$3 becomes #ref also if in T3 there is the shifted value, because it lost the reference (But there is still a value in T3!). Is there an easy way to "LOCK" that cell so that if I delete it, the formula is still good?

Answer (score 0):

Use `INDIRECT` for any ranges that might be deleted:

```
=OFFSET(INDIRECT("'Acq HORIBA'!$T$3"),Rifasamento!$C$40,0,5000-Rifasamento!$C$40+1,1)
```